# Why does SNAP let me open some Sentinel-5p products and not others?

Tags: atmosphere, remote-sensing, air-quality

Good morning,

I am working with **Sentinel-5p products**, my final thesis is to establish a methodology for processing this type of images, from downloading to the implementation of a colour map with the different distributions according to concentrations.
Any help on this subject is of great help to me.

I download the products from ''Sentinel-5p Pre-operations Data Hub'', but the L2, ozone and sulphur dioxide products do not open in SNAP(Sentinel Application Platform)  CO, NO and the aerosol index do open.
I have read other forums and they tell me that they are not compatible and that I should download toolboxes, but I don't know how to do it.

I would be very grateful to anyone who has worked with me and would like to help me.

Thanks

Comment: This one perhaps? https://atmospherictoolbox.org/

Comment: I'm not familiar with SNAP, but it's possible that the products not opening have different data elements or more dimensions than what SNAP expects.  Are you using HDF files?

Comment: I think asking the question in [gis stack exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) may be helpful for you

Comment: Thank you for all the answers.
@Jean-Marie Prival, do you know how I can incorporate these tools into SNAP. Or how I can make use of them?

Comment: @f.thorpe Sentinel-5p products are netCDF files.

Comment: Not sure if this thread is useful https://forum.step.esa.int/t/sentinel-5p-raster-creation/11342   or this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G8tVNbdu8-A or personally I might start with this tool but I am partial to python:  https://github.com/bilelomrani1/s5p-tools